# How to Acknowledge In App Subscriptions in React Native using React Native IAP

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

Good morning Developers,
I have been trying to Acknowledge payments for android after using React Native IAP library to accept subscriptions in my app put it seems not to be working.

I am using context API in my app and below is my code:

```js
import React, { createContext, useState,useEffect, useContext,  } from 'react';
import RNIap, {
    InAppPurchase,
    PurchaseError,
    SubscriptionPurchase,
    acknowledgePurchaseAndroid,
    consumePurchaseAndroid,
    finishTransaction,
    finishTransactionIOS,
    purchaseErrorListener,
    purchaseUpdatedListener,
  } from 'react-native-iap';
import { Alert, Platform, } from 'react-native'
import { Container, Header, Content, Toast, Button, Text } from 'native-base';

export const IApContext = createContext();

const itemSkus = Platform.select({
    ios: [
        'kriss.once.removeads',
        'kriss.sub.removeads'
    ],
    android: [
        'com.sublegal.submonthly',
]
});
export const IApController = ({ children }) => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    const [showads, setShowads] = useState(true);
    const [wascalled, setWascalled] = useState(false);

    const initIAp = async () => {
        try {
            await RNIap.initConnection();

            
            purchaseUpdateSubscription = purchaseUpdatedListener(
                async (purchase= SubscriptionPurchase) => {
                    console.log('purchase', purchase);
                  
                  const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt
                    ? purchase.transactionReceipt
                    : purchase.originalJson;
                    console.log(receipt)
                 
                  if (receipt) {
                    try {
                        acknowledgePurchaseAndroid(purchase.purchaseToken);
                      const ackResult =  acknowledgePurchaseAndroid(purchase.purchaseToken);
                      console.info('ackResult', ackResult);
                       RNIap.finishTransaction(purchase, true);
                    } catch (ackErr) {
                      console.warn('ackErr', ackErr);
                    }
            
                  
                  }
                },
              );
          } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err.code, err.message);
          }
    
          
          
      
try {
            const products = await RNIap.getProducts(itemSkus);
            if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                const subscription = await RNIap.getSubscriptions(itemSkus);
                products.push(subscription[0])
            }

            console.log(products)
          setProducts({products});
if (products) {
                setWascalled(true)
            } else {
                setWascalled(false)
            }
            console.log(wascalled)
            
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err); // standardized err.code and err.message available
        }
    }

    
    makeSubscription = async (sku) => {
        try {
            RNIap.requestSubscription(sku);
   toggleAds(false)
   purchaseUpdateSubscription = purchaseUpdatedListener(
    async (purchase= SubscriptionPurchase) => {
        console.log('purchase', purchase);
      
      const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt
        ? purchase.transactionReceipt
        : purchase.originalJson;
        console.log(receipt)
     
      if (receipt) {
        try {
            acknowledgePurchaseAndroid(purchase.purchaseToken);
          const ackResult = acknowledgePurchaseAndroid(purchase.purchaseToken);
          console.info('ackResult', ackResult);
           RNIap.finishTransaction(purchase, true);
        } catch (ackErr) {
          console.warn('ackErr', ackErr);
        }

      
      }
    },
  );
  
         
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err.code, err.message);
        }
    }



    checkValidPurchase = async () => {
        try {
            const purchases = await RNIap.getAvailablePurchases();

            purchases.forEach(async (purchase) => {
                switch (purchase.productId) {
                  case 'com.sublegal.submonthly':
                        // await AsyncStorage.setItem('removeadsmonthly', JSON.stringify(res));
                       toggleAds(false)
                       console.warn('No 1 purchase is available');
                       break

                  //     case 'com.myproduct.blegal':
                        //   await AsyncStorage.setItem('removeadsmonthly', JSON.stringify(res));
                    //     toggleAds(false)
                     //      break
                    case 'com.kriss.remove_ads_monthly':
                        // await AsyncStorage.setItem('removeadsmonthly', JSON.stringify(res));
                        toggleAds(false)
                        break
                    case 'com.kriss.remove_ad_forever':
                        //   await AsyncStorage.setItem('removeadsmonthly', JSON.stringify(res));
                        toggleAds(false)
                        break
                    default: console.warn('you do not have any purchase');

                }
            })

        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err);
        }
    }


    
    const toggleAds = value => {
        if (value === true) {
            setShowads(true);
        } else {
            setShowads(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <IApContext.Provider value={{
            initIAp,
          
            wascalled,
            showads,
            checkValidPurchase,
            products,
           
            makeSubscription,
        }}>
            {children}
        </IApContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

With the above code i can make subscriptions but my users get refunded in three days because payments are not acknowledge. I really need help on how to solve this problem. The app is already up on google playstore.

Comment: Guys please i need help!

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things incorrect with your code. Your current code is setup for acknowledging a consumable purchase, with subscriptions the parameters are slightly different.

1. `acknowledgePurchaseAndroid();` is expecting an object not a string. The correct format would be `acknowledgePurchaseAndroid({token: purchase.purchaseToken});`
2. `RNIap.finishTransaction(purchase, true);` the second value is for if the IAP is a consumable or not. The correct format for subscriptions would be `RNIap.finishTransaction(purchase, false);` or if you want to keep the code easy to read for future references if you plan to send values not as variables `RNIap.finishTransaction({purchase:purchase, isConsumable: false}`

Comment: I think we need to pass with variables because without that it gives an error, error like ```Argument of type '{ currentPurchase: RNIap.Purchase; isConsumable: true; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ purchase: Purchase; isConsumable?: boolean; developerPayloadAndroid?: string; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'currentPurchase' does not exist in type '{ purchase: Purchase; isConsumable?: boolean; developerPayloadAndroid?: string; }'```

Comment: Your problem is different from @samuel-edeh . The problem with your error is that you are using a parameter key that is not expected by the `finishTransaction` method.  You need to replace `currentPurchase` to `purchase` for the key.